# Pandas: convert series of time stamps keeping the YYYY-MM-DD format only

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime

Say you want to create a series of time stamps in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` from `1990-1-1` to `1991-12-31` with `pandas`:

```
import pandas
import datetime

start = datetime.date(1990, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(1991, 12, 31)
s = pandas.Series(pandas.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='D'))
```

The result is:

```
In[1]: s
Out[1]:
0     1990-01-01
1     1990-01-02
2     1990-01-03
3     1990-01-04
...
```

How can I turn `s` into a list? If I do

```
In[2]: s.tolist()
Out[2]: 
[Timestamp('1990-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1990-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1990-01-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1990-01-04 00:00:00'),
...
```

Not only do I get the date, but also additional information which I don't need. **My question:** how can I get the `YYYY-MM-DD` (string) values only from `s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to output your dates in your desired string format:

```
In [114]:
s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').head()

Out[114]:
0    1990-01-01
1    1990-01-02
2    1990-01-03
3    1990-01-04
4    1990-01-05
dtype: object

In [115]:
s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').head().tolist()

Out[115]:
['1990-01-01', '1990-01-02', '1990-01-03', '1990-01-04', '1990-01-05']
```

Note though that you cannot modify pandas date display format when the dtype is datetime, you can only generate a string in the format you desired but this is less useful IMO

**update**

if you're getting unicode strings then you can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings to convert them into regular strings

Comment: Uhm.... interesting... I get data stamps with a unicode symbol such as `u'1990-1-1'`. How to get rid of it?

Comment: I'm using python 3, is yours python 2?

Comment: Yes, sorry LOL... should have mentioned that

Comment: you may need to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings I'd just do a list comprehension to handle that